If presheaves over C are generated by subterminal objects, is C is a posetal category?
I am trying to understand one of firsts statements in the proof of the lemma C5.2.4 of Johnstone's Sketches of an Elephant. It says that, for a small category $\mathcal{C}$, the existence of a surjective discrete opfibration $\mathcal{P} \to \mathcal{C}$ where $\mathcal{P}$ is a poset, is equivalent to the condition of $[\mathcal{C},\mathbf{Set}]$ having a well supported object whose slice is localic. I am having trouble proving the existence of such an opfibration.
If $A \colon \mathcal{C} \to \mathbf{Set}$ is a well supported object, the Grothendieck opfibration $\mathcal{G}(A) \to \mathcal{C}$ is a discrete surjective one but, is $\mathcal{G}(A)$ a posetal category?
I thought that it might be easier to solve the problem asked in the title of this post, but I couldn't prove it nor found a counterexample. I am looking for a hint that helps me complete the proof.

I think a presheaf generated by subterminals must satisfy the condition that for every parallel pair $f, g \in \mathcal{C}(c, d)$, $A(f) = A(g)$.  If that's the case for each functor $\mathcal{C}(c, {-})$, that would imply that all parallel pairs are equal.  Which I think would make $\mathcal{C}$ at least a preorder category, or equivalent to a poset category.

That helped a lot! Thank you very much.
